# Subnetting Router with Passthrough Modem

Tags: networking, router, modem

In my home, I have a modem connected to the Internet, and I have a wireless router connected to the modem.

It was working fine. I took some notes a while back when I first got it configured, but I am not sure if these were the latest settings.

> Modem

```
IP Address: 192.168.2.254 / 255.255.255.0
DHCP Range: 192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.5
```

> Router

```
LAN IP Add: 192.168.0.1 / 255.255.255.0
WAN IP Add: 192.168.2.1 / 255.255.255.0
Gateway:    192.168.2.254
Prim. DNS:  192.168.2.254
DHCP Range: 192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.199
```

Now for the change:

I bought a new **NAS** (network storage). I plugged it in, but it did not show up.

Using the NAS software, I was able to see that it is configured for a specific network:

> NAS

```
IP Add: 192.168.1.5
```

The IP Address of the NAS can be changed by browsing to the NAS on the network, but I cannot reach it. I'm not really sure how the NAS software was able to see it across the domain name, but it did. That is not the point.

I can only access items that use the **Router's DHCP Range** (currently `192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.199`).

I tried making changes to my network to accommodate it, but now I cannot get from my LAN out to the Internet.

I took a number of router classes 10+ years ago, but I never used it and the books and notes from those classes are long gone.

How would I modify my Modem's and Router's network settings so that the **NAS IP Address** `192.168.1.5` falls in the **Router's DHCP Range**?

If I get a nice, complete answer, I can print that out and keep it with my modem and router in my little network closet.

Comment: If you set your computer's IP to 192.168.1.6 / 255.255.255.0 / gateway leave blank, DNS leave blank, and you are plugged into the same router/switch combo that you have, you should then be able to hit the web UI of the NAS. Once there, you can change it to DHCP (if it is't and it will pickup an address in the 0.100 -0.199 range, or just set a static IP on it of 192.168.0.50 or something similar. I am going to guess that the NAS was just unfortunately set to static out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, we should not change the whole network to accommodate a NAS. Why not just connect your computer and the NAS with UTP Cat 5e directly and configure the IP address of your computer with 192.168.1.10/24. You should be able to access the NAS after that. Then change the IP address of the NAS to subnet 192.168.0.0/24 and put it back to your network.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A lot of what you say looks foreign to me. UTP Cat 5e? Are you saying to connect a network cable directly from my PC to the NAS? What is `/24?` My network is currently messed up, and I would like a way to understand it so I can get it right this time and in the future.

Comment: what he (and narzard) are saying is: plug the computer into the NAS (or the router), and then **set the computer IP address manually** to something on the same subnet. Your LAN is on x.x.0.x, your modem is on x.x.2.x and your NAS is on x.x.1.x. So put your computer manually to the subnet x.x.1.x, and then connect to the NAS, make the changes, then set your computer back to DHCP automatic

Comment: @jp2code Sorry, I'm not clear in my first reply. The UTP Cat 5e is the network cable. Bad habit of a network engineer :-). /24 is the subnet mask, it is same with 255.255.255.0. Yorik has explained my intention very well.